# Three.js mesh position toJSON()

Tags: three.js

I have an issue, using `.toJSON()` and `.ObjectLoader()`.
I'm creating a mesh object (Object3D) with a position and converting it into JSON.

```
mesh.position.set(path.x, path.y, path.z);

Mesh {
uuid: 'AAA36A25-18C6-43CD-AF14-4D12826A8C06',
name: '',
type: 'Mesh',
parent: null,
children: [],
up: Vector3 { x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 },
position: Vector3 { x: 358.04999999981374, y: -4499.83, z: 
2521.2299999999814 },

var mesh_tojson = mesh.toJSON();

{ metadata: { version: 4.5, type: 'Object', generator: 'Object3D.toJSON' },
geometries:
[ { uuid: '0E18D023-CC64-4D83-AB28-C731BB1E5B1B',
   type: 'OctahedronGeometry',
   radius: 100,
   detail: 0 } ],
materials:
[ { uuid: '055D52FD-0767-44D8-A62F-C1514FE38111',
   type: 'MeshLambertMaterial',
   color: 16776960,
   emissive: 0,
   depthFunc: 3,
   depthTest: true,
   depthWrite: true,
   rotation: undefined,
   linewidth: undefined } ],
object:
 { uuid: 'AAA36A25-18C6-43CD-AF14-4D12826A8C06',
 type: 'Mesh',
 matrix: [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
 geometry: '0E18D023-CC64-4D83-AB28-C731BB1E5B1B',
 material: '055D52FD-0767-44D8-A62F-C1514FE38111' } }
```

But when I try to load the JSON object, everything is good except I loose the position attribute of my mesh object.

```
var mesh = loader.parse(mesh.toJSON())

Mesh {
uuid: 'AAA36A25-18C6-43CD-AF14-4D12826A8C06',
name: '',
type: 'Mesh',
parent: null,
children: [],
up: Vector3 { x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 },
position: Vector3 { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
```

How can I save the position of my object within a JSON object and load it for a scene ?

Answer (score 1):

In the [code for `.toJSON()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/4ffb5be895319fb5a61496b8103262a31af9c1c8/src/core/Object3D.js#L612-L746), position and rotation are not included. You can manually add them to the JSON:

```
mesh.matrix.toArray( json.object.matrix )
```

You may also need to manually re-apply them after loading, I'm not sure if THREE.ObjectLoader will do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `mesh.updateMatrix()` before `mesh.toJSON()` ... [it worked for me](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/23871#issuecomment-1093798077).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
model3D.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                child.updateMatrix();
            }
        });
```